как использовать Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3 с помощью torch и transformers?
Я пытаюсь начать использование LLM модели Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3
Чтобы ее использовать я использую код из Hugging Face создателей:
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

model_id = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)

def get_current_weather(location: str, format: str):
    """
    Get the current weather

    Args:
        location: The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA
        format: The temperature unit to use. Infer this from the users location. (choices: ["celsius", "fahrenheit"])
    """
    pass

conversation = [{"role": "user", "content": "What's the weather like in Paris?"}]
tools = [get_current_weather]


# format and tokenize the tool use prompt 
inputs = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
            conversation,
            tools=tools,
            add_generation_prompt=True,
            return_dict=True,
            return_tensors="pt",
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16, device_map="auto")

inputs.to(model.device)
outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=1000)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True))

Но у меня появляется ошибка:
*SError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this file, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3 is not the path to a directory containing a file named config.json.
Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.*

И я не могу ее никак решить, интернет соединение нормальное, путь и название модели вроде правильное, в свой аккаунт HF я в питоне вошел.
Если нужны еще уточнения пишите я добавлю информации.

можно попробовать несколько способов. Во-первых, проверьте, сохранена ли модель локально (на вашем компьютере), потому что иногда бывают проблемы с подключением. Используйте такую команду для проверки, from transformers import is_remote_url;  print(is_remote_url(model_id)). Если интернет работает нормально, но ошибка всё равно есть, попробуйте скачать модель вручную. Держи меня в курсе. Скажи мне, если это работает.

Говорит что в transformers нет is_remote_url, что это значит? Интернет работает у меня нормально, я думаю если не получится таким способом, действительно придется скачивать вручную(

Я обновил библиотеку transformers и посмотрел, у нее нет такой функции, но я нашел аналогичный метод проверки вроде как, используя
**import re;
def is_remote_url(model_id):
return re.match(r'^(http|https)://', model_id) is not None
model_id = "https://huggingface.co/some-model";
print(is_remote_url(model_id)**
мне вывело True - типо это URL

@RevolucionforMonica

Если is_remote_url возвращает True и проблема сохраняется, действительно необходимо загрузить модель вручную. Для этого просто перейдите на страницу шаблона Hugging Face, загрузите его и сохраните локально. Затем мы можем заменить model_id на путь к модели, загруженной на компьютер.
